# What is the code of jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file) return null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

I'm trying to convert my xml file with java jabx , but in my case I don't get any error but it still returns null object, I use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` , to get only the file I want.

```java
ListMessageUser que = (ListMessageUser) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
//[dateGen=null, listMessages=null]
```

exemple imput file XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListMessageUser xmlns="https://myapp.fr/schema">
    <DateGen>2022-06-17T11:01:43Z</DateGen>
    <ListMessages>
        <Message>
            <Name>test</Name>
            <Description>Message test</Description>
            <DateMAJ>2022-04-15T12:47:39Z</DateMAJ>
        </Message>
        ....
    </ListMessages>
<Signature xmlns="...">
    <SignedInfo></SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
    ...
</Signature>
</ListMessageUser>
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "https://myapp.fr/schema", name = "ListMessageUser")
public class ListMessageUser {
    
    private String dateGen;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ListMessages")
    @XmlElement(name="Message")
    private List<MessageXml> listMessages;

    /// Constructor
    /// Getters and setters
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class MessageXml {
    
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date dateMAJ;
    
    /// Constructor
    /// Getters and setters
}
```

can someone tell me what is wrong with my code ?

or clue ?

example log trace execution

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory      : SAXParserFactory instance: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl@511a307e
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startDocument
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startPrefixMapping: :https://myapp.fr/schema
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:ListMessageUser:ListMessageUser, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:DateGen:DateGen, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:DateGen:DateGen
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:ListeMessages:ListeMessages, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Message:Message
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Message:Message, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Name:Name, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Name:Name
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Description:Description, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Description:Description
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:DateMAJ:DateMAJ, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:DateMAJ:DateMAJ
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:Message:Message
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
...
...
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:ListeMessages:ListeMessages
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@42a7e7e1
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startPrefixMapping: :http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature:Signature, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignedInfo:SignedInfo, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignedInfo:SignedInfo
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignatureValue:SignatureValue, attrs: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$AttributesProxy@334d825c
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.push
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.characters: [C@152dbf8e
...
...
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature:Signature
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.endPrefixMapping: 
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.startElement: https://myapp.fr/schema:ListMessageUser:ListMessageUser
c.s.x.b.v.r.u.UnmarshallingContext       : State.pop
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.endPrefixMapping: 
c.s.x.b.v.r.unmarshaller.SAXConnector    : SAXConnector.endDocument
```

the problem seems to come namespaceURI xmlns="https://myapp.fr/schema".

How Can fix that